# Writing to remote computer registry

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, registry, admin

I seem to keep running into issues changing a registry key on remote computers.
This command is to enable the UAT box to appear on the masters computer instead of the novice computer and remote that stupid pause symbol

```
public void SecureDesktopEnable(Object ComputerName)
{
    String CurrentUser = Environment.UserDomainName + "\\" + Environment.UserName;

    System.Security.AccessControl.RegistrySecurity RegSec = new System.Security.AccessControl.RegistrySecurity();
    RegSec.AddAccessRule(new System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryAccessRule(
        Environment.UserDomainName + "\\" + Environment.UserName,
          System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryRights.WriteKey 
        | System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryRights.ReadKey
        | System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryRights.SetValue, 
        System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags.None,
        System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags.None,
        System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Allow));

    RegistryKey RegistryEntry = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, ComputerName.ToString(),RegistryView.Registry64)
        .OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System", true);
    RegistryEntry.SetAccessControl(RegSec);

    if ((bool)SecureDesktop)
    {
        RegistryEntry.SetValue("PromptOnSecureDesktop", 1, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
    }
    else
    {
        RegistryEntry.SetValue("PromptOnSecureDesktop", 0, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
    }
    
}

    private bool _SecureDesktop;
    public bool SecureDesktop { get { return _SecureDesktop; } set { _SecureDesktop = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("SecureDesktop"); } }
```

i am getting to this point

```
.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System", true);
```

and I get error message

> Requested Registry access is not allowed.

using the same username and password I can open regedit, connect to network registry and change the key.

I have also added

```
<requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

and

```
<requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="true" />
```

in the app.manifest file.